# How to add a modal pop up on the view button?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card card-profile">
            <div class="card-avatar">
              <a href="#pablo">
                <img class="img" src="{% static 'img/faces/marc.jpg' %}">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-category text-gray">CEO / Co-Founder</h5>
              <h4 class="card-title">{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</h4>
                <h6 class="card-category text-gray">ILO - 001</h6>
                <h6 class="card-category text-gray">HOME HEALTH</h6>
              <p class="card-description">
                  Monday to Friday (9AM to 6PM)
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-round">View</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

The code for an Profile Pic on my main page, and I was trying to add a modal pop to wherein when I click the View button it will show the whole profile of the employee. And i don't have an idea how to do this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you read this documentation? [Bootstrap Modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this bootstrap 4 CDN (**Content Delivery Network**) into your HTML page inside `head` tag

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The Modal component is a dialog box/popup window that is displayed on top of the current page

The following **example** shows how to create a basic modal

```
<!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Open modal
</button>
```

InSide `modal-body` you can put your code whatever either you put employee profile whatever you want

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body..
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you want some animation Use the `.fade` class to add a fading effect when opening and closing the modal

Change the size of the modal by adding the `.modal-sm` class for **small modals**, `.modal-lg` class for **large modals**, or `.modal-xl` for **extra large modals**.

Center the modal vertically and horizontally within the page, with the `.modal-dialog-centered` class

Read More about modal documentation [Click Here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp)

You can edit or preview code [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G9G62UD3APGE)